# Sorting an array based on comparison with another array of same elements in different order

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Given two arrays

```
a[] = {1,3,2,4} 
b[] = {4,2,3,1}
```

both will have the same numbers but in different order.
We have to sort **both of them**. The condition is that you **cannot** compare elements within the same array.

Comment: Does this make sense to anyone?

Comment: I don't quite understand.  Are you transforming b until it has the same order as a?  In which case, aren't you always just returning a?

Comment: If the interview questions were like this, I'd pass up the job. Really.

Comment: Come on, this is not the weirdest interview questions at all. Just accept the reality.

Comment: @Mu Qiao - it was weird before it was fixed up by an editor prior to your viewing.

Comment: @hatchet probably fixed by me :)

Comment: @Mu Qiao - sure enough! missed that when I looked at the edit :)

Answer (score 5):

I can give you an algorithm of **O(N*log(N))** time complexity based on quick sort.

1. Randomly select an element a1 in array A
2. Use a1 to partition array B, note that you only have to compare every element in array B with a1
3. Partitioning returns the position b1. Use b1 to partition array A (the same as step 2)
4. Go to step 1 for the partitioned sub-arrays if their length are greater than 1.

Time complexity: **T(N) = 2*T(N/2) + O(N)**. So the overall complexity is O(N*log(N)) according to master theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understood the question properly, but from my understanding the task is a follows:

> Sort a given array `a` *without* comparing any two elements from `a` directly. However we are given a second array `b` which is guaranteed to contain the same elements as `a` but in arbitrary order. You are not allowed to modify `b` (otherwise just sort `b` and return it...).

In case the elements in `a` are distinct this is easy: for every element in `a` count how many elements in `b` are smaller. This number gives us the (zero based) index in a sorted order.

The case where elements are not necessarily distinct is left to the reader :)

Comment: Right good working solution. It's O(n^2). The solutions expected was to be in O(nlogn)

Comment: Of Course you could construct a BST of `b` to get it to O(nlogn) but that kind of is the same as sorting `b` right away...